# How to make synchronized method in Angular service?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular 15 application that have a few components which invoking the service method to retrieve some data from the backend. Before the execution the service is checking is there is a required data in the local cache. If there is no data then the service executes the endpoint and store the retrieved data in the cache. In the code it looks so:

```
export class CryptoMarketService implements MarketService {
   private _activeOrdersCache: Cache<Array<Order>> = new Cache<Array<Order>>();
   ...
    getActiveOrders(): Observable<Array<Order>> {   // the method should be syncrhonized
       if (this._activeOrdersCache.hasCache()) {
           return of(this._activeOrdersCache.get());
       }

       return this.httpClient.get('/market/orders/active')
        .pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                return Order.fromJsonArray(res);
            }),
            tap((activeOrders: Array<Order>) => {
                this._activeOrdersCache.set(activeOrders, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            })
        );
}
```

But a few components are invoking that method simultaneously so in fact they are both invoking the backend (because the cache can't be initialized in time) and only after getting the response the cache is populating twice.
So is there a way to make that service method synchronized (like in java) to make the second thread wait until the first thread is finished, and start the execution the getActiveOrders method only when the cache is settled?

Is the angular have some mechanism like synchronized like in Java or C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't cache the result, but the observable itself, and share it by using `shareReplay()`.

```ts
export class CryptoMarketService implements MarketService {
  private _activeOrdersCache: Cache<Observable<Array<Order>>> = new Cache<Observable<Array<Order>>>();

  getActiveOrders(): Observable<Array<Order>> {
    if (!this._activeOrdersCache.hasCache()) {
      const obs = this.httpClient.get('/market/orders/active')
        .pipe(
          ...
          shareReplay(1)
        );
      this._activeOrdersCache.set(obs, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    return this._activeOrdersCache.get();
  }
}
```

All subscribers will receive the same observable and the result of the stream at that point will be shared, meaning the HTTP call and pipeable operators before `shareReplay()` will only run once.

Answer (score 3):

you could put observables/promises in cache, instead of the resulting values. this way it will automatically be there when one "thread"(ofc it is not) has already executed the code.

but more angular way would be to just use observables built in methods

```
export class CryptoMarketService implements MarketService {
   private _activeOrders$ = this.httpClient.get('/market/orders/active').pipe(
     map(Order.fromJsonArray), 
     shareReplay(1)
   );
   ...
    getActiveOrders(): Observable<Array<Order>> {
      this.activeOrder$;
    }
```

observables are lazy, and won't make a call untill someone subscribes to it. and `share`ing makes sure all the calls would share the same call. And also it is way shorter than manual cache implementation and usage

Comment: This approach is cleaner if you only have a single request. But it does not consider cache invalidation.

Comment: In this case, you can just skip the method and just expose the observable as public.

Comment: yes, you are right. do you have predescribed invalidation logic, or you rather want to invalidate it from the imperative code?

Comment: Hi Andrei! Your answer is correct, thank you! But in my case I should use the manual caching because we need to cache all future requests in the closest few minutes also

Comment: I would go the way described in answers to this question in your case @AlexanderKozlov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752623/rxjs-sharereplay-with-invalidation-timeout